# LIKE command not working on host

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014, sql-like

I have this query:

```
SELECT * FROM Takhfif WHERE TakhfifName LIKE '%keyword%' AND CityID=2
```

This is an example. I have dynamic version of this code.

This code is working great on local but not working in host!

My local SQL Server is 2014
and the host SQL Server is 2012.

If this code doesn't work on SQL Server 2012 what code should I use for an exact search?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: remove double quotes (").

Comment: oops, that is for c# code!

Comment: without error!!

Comment: Please describe the detail on how it doesn't work. Any error message?

Comment: @KooSengSeng no without any error.

Comment: So the query doesn't return anything? From the query itself, there doesn't seems to have any problem. The code work for MSSQL 2008. Perhaps is the issue with the `keyword` or `CityID=2`, and there is no data for that. Try to remove the `CityID=2` condition and execute only the provided query in host server, see if any data is being returned.

Comment: @KooSengSeng no no Database is full of data

Comment: I mean, try to execute the query that you provided by reducing the condition and see if it would return data. Sometimes it's the condition that unexpectedly causes query doesn't pick up data. Need to do some trial there

Comment: I'm betting there is no value "keyword" in the TakhfifName column... or is "keyword" a parameter you are using @AmirTvs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somethings to consider

1. Searching single keyword in a column.(Keyword1, Keyword2, Keyword3)
2. Searching keyword in a string in a column (Looking for this Keyword1
   in a sentence)

Try your keyword with space around it.

```
SELECT * FROM Takhfif WHERE TakhfifName LIKE ' %keyword% ' AND CityID=2
SELECT * FROM Takhfif WHERE TakhfifName LIKE '% keyword %' AND CityID=2
```

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

> this is an example i have dynamic version of this code.

This makes me think you are using a variable... I explain that below

> However this code is working great on local but not working in host!

This code will not provide different results regardless if you run it in SQL Server 2008, 2012, 2016, etc...

> my local Sql Server is 2014 and the host sql server is 2012

This doesn't matter, unless the data is different (not mirrored / replicated)

> if this code not working on sql server 2012 what code should i use for
>   a exact search?

You stated "it isn't working". If you want "exact" then you only use the `=` operator... not the `LIKE` function.

```
WHERE TakhfifName = 'keyword'
--or if you have a variable
WHERE TakhfifName = @keyword
```

Either you are literally trying to search for the work `keyword` and it obviously doesn't exist or you aren't certain on how to use the `LIKE` function in SQL Server correctly. Consider these examples...

```
declare @Takhfif table (TakhfifName varchar (64), CityID int)
insert into @Takhfif (TakhfifName, CityID) values
('United States',1),
('China',1),
('Russia',1),
('Brazil',1),
('France',1),
('Japan',2),
('Morocco',2)

--This query will return records where CityID = 1 and the letters ra are located anywhere in the TakhfifName
SELECT * 
FROM @Takhfif 
WHERE TakhfifName LIKE '%ra%' AND CityID=1

--This query will return records where CityID = 1 and the letter a is located at the END of the name
SELECT * 
FROM @Takhfif 
WHERE TakhfifName LIKE '%a' AND CityID=1

--This query will return records where CityID = 1 and the letter C is located at the beginning of the name
SELECT * 
FROM @Takhfif 
WHERE TakhfifName LIKE 'c%' AND CityID=1

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
--If you want to use these with a variable, you have to use concatonation
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

declare @variable varchar(16)

set @variable = 'ra'
--This query will return records where CityID = 1 and the letters ra are located anywhere in the TakhfifName
SELECT * 
FROM @Takhfif 
WHERE TakhfifName LIKE '%' + @variable + '%' AND CityID=1

set @variable = '%a'
--This query will return records where CityID = 1 and the letter a is located at the END of the name
SELECT * 
FROM @Takhfif 
WHERE TakhfifName LIKE '%' + @variable AND CityID=1

set @variable = 'c%'
--This query will return records where CityID = 1 and the letter C is located at the beginning of the name
SELECT * 
FROM @Takhfif 
WHERE TakhfifName LIKE @variable + '%' AND CityID=1
```